# Java threads: Running a simple java thread program output confusion

Tags: java, multithreading

```
class Runner extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Counting "+i);
        }
    }
}
public class App {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Runner runner1=new Runner();
        runner1.start();
        Runner runner2=new Runner();
        runner2.start();
    }
}
```

I was just going through the basics of threads in java. The expected output is :

```
Counting 0
Counting 0
Counting 1
Counting 1
Counting 2
Counting 2
Counting 3
Counting 3
Counting 4
Counting 4
```

But am getting an output like this cant seem to reason this out:

```
Counting 0
Counting 1
Counting 2
Counting 3
Counting 4
Counting 0
Counting 1
Counting 2
Counting 3
Counting 4
```

Comment: your expectation is wrong not the output :)

Comment: the counting display order will change. Because two threads are running simultaniously not one after another.

Comment: You may need to count to 100 or 1000 to see the output interleave.  The first thread completes while you're still starting the second thread from `main()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any kind of synchronization, there can be no expectation to the order of execution (and interleaving of instructions) for multiple threads.

In your example, you could get your expected output by putting long pauses (Thread.sleep) into each iteration of the loop (still technically not guaranteed, but practically speaking unavoidable).

Answer (score 0):

Please provide Thread sleep in your code. It will run concurrently between both the threads.

```
System.out.println("counting"+i)
Thread.sleep(500)
```

Please Insert these code in the run method.IT will work as you want